# System.UnauthorizedAccessException error? I tried the Envirorment.getfolderpath/running as admin, but nothing works

Tags: c#

```
static void SendMail()
{
  String SystemErrors = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");

  String filepath = @"C:\Windows\Boot\";
  string filepath2 = filepath + @"\SystemErrors\somefile.text";
  {
    if (!Directory.Exists(filepath2))
      Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\Windows\Boot\SystemErrors\somefile.txt");

    if (!File.Exists(filepath2))
      File.Create(filepath2);
}
```

Im trying to create a new folder and file.text, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Even `SYSTEM` only has read access to `%windir%\Boot`. In fact, by default, the only account that can write here is `Trusted Installer`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using the `Exists` methods correctly.

You must call [`File.Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netframework-4.7.2) when you want to check if a **file** exists, and you must provide the path to the file.

[`Directory.Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?view=netframework-4.7.2) must be called when you want to check if a **directory** exists, and you must provide the path to the directory.